# Entity Framework - DbMigrator not executing migration classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an issue executing migrations using DbMigrator, somehow the migration classes are not executed and of course doesn't reflect in the database.

What I'm trying to implement is group my migrations to versions.  Basically I have a Version base class in which all versions are derived from.

For example I have a class Version1000 which corresponds to version 1.0.0.0.

Version classes has a method called ExecuteMigrations which is responsible for executing migrations related to the version it corresponds.

Here's a sample of a version class (Version1000 for 1.0.0.0), see the ExecuteMigrations method using DbMigrator, it also uses a VersionConfiguration class which derives from DbMigrationsConfiguration, it is in there where I set the namespaces, the directory, the ContextType.. etc..

```
public class Version1000 : Version
{
    public override string VersionNumber
    {
        get { return "1.0.0.0"; }
    } 

    public static Version Version
    {
        get
        {
            return new Version1000();
        }
    }

    public override void ExecuteMigrations()
    {
        var configuration = new VersionConfiguration();
        configuration.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(MyCustomContext.CONTEXT_CONNECTION_STRING_NAME);
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        migrator.Update();
    }
}
```

VersionConfiguration Class

```
class VersionConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyCustomContext>
{
    public VersionConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsNamespace = "Some.Namespace._1000";
        MigrationsDirectory = "Migration\\1000";
        ContextType = typeof(MyCustomContext);
    }

    protected override void Seed(MyCustomContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

At application start of my application what I do is check the current version of my database and then apply versions which are not applied to the current database. This is done by calling the ExecuteMigrations method of the version class.

The thing is I don't get any exceptions its just that the changes are not reflected to the database when the DbMigrator.Update method is called and the migration classes in the folder/namespace which is set in the DbMigrationsConfiguration where never executed.

Application Type: ASP.NET MVC 4 
.NET Framework: 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your migration should also implement IVersionMetadata and must provide an Id, Source and Target property. They should have values similar to those:

```
Id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", SomeSequenceNumber.ToString().PadLeft(15, '0'), "Name")
Source = null
Target = "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";
```

Maybe some clarifications about the Target parameter: it contains a compressed version of a whole model. They want to remove the necessity to give a Target in EF, however, even the EF6 alpha3 still requires this. The string given above is the compressed format of an empty model, I just put that as a constant and it works like a charm...

Also: In my project I had the wrong Id format and it didn't do anything. Need to find out more about that in the EF source soon, however, for now maybe this helps your case!

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, your code looks very strange. Where is entity classes or reference to them? What entities/database objects are included in 1.0.0.0 version?

As code-first says, you must describe your entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace StartReg.Data {        
    public class UserSession {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserSessionId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset LogonTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string LogonIPAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength()]
        public string LogonUserAgent { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

Add it to DbContext:

```
namespace StartReg.Data {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class StartRegDb : DbContext {
        public StartRegDb()
            : base("DefaultConnection") {
        }

        public DbSet<Distance> Distances { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And when you then execute in Package Manager Console (do you have NuGet installed?) commands `Enable-Migrations` and `Add-Miration Version1000` you will recieve migration configuraton

```
namespace StartReg.Migrations {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;
    using StartReg.Data;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<StartReg.Data.StartRegDb> {
        public Configuration() {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(StartReg.Data.StartRegDb context) {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
        }
    }
}
```

And Version1000 migration class:

namespace StartReg.Migrations {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

```
public partial class Initial : DbMigration {
    public override void Up() {

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Distances",
            c => new {
                DistanceId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                MeetingId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Key = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 20),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                Ordering = c.Short(nullable: false),
                AllowMale = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                AllowFemale = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.DistanceId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Meetings", t => t.MeetingId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.MeetingId)
            .Index(t => new { MeetingId = t.MeetingId, Ordering = t.Ordering });
    }

    public override void Down() {
        DropTable("dbo.Distances");
    }
}
```

}

And after that you need place somewhere before any real work with database (Application_Start for example):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<StartRegDb, StartReg.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

And when app is started - table Distances is automatically created in database.

Comment: I do have migration classes which derives from DbMigration and yes there are statements in there that creates tables just like in your example.  If you tried to look out the custom DBMigrationsConfiguration (VersionConfiguration), it is set in there the namespace of the migration classes and the folder where it is located but somehow its not executing them.